# Away3d - Error #3691: Resource limit for this resource type exceeded

Tags: actionscript-3, stage3d, away3d

I'm stuck on an error that I can't make go away.

I'm using Away3d with a skybox as a panorama player, after changing the skybox texture a few times I sometimes get this error.  I'm not sure if it's only happening in debug player only.

I assume something is not being cleared out but I can't work out what.

I could change the skybox to a simple geometry and see if that's better, then I can absolutely make sure the textures are disposed.

Anyone any clues?

```
Error: Error #3691: Resource limit for this resource type exceeded.
    at flash.display3D::Context3D/createCubeTexture()
    at away3d.textures::CubeTextureBase/createTexture()[C:\workspace\flash\libs\lib_pano_away3d\src\away3d\textures\CubeTextureBase.as:25]
    at away3d.textures::TextureProxyBase/getTextureForStage3D()[C:\workspace\flash\libs\lib_pano_away3d\src\away3d\textures\TextureProxyBase.as:65]
    at away3d.materials.passes::SkyBoxPass/activate()[C:\workspace\flash\libs\lib_pano_away3d\src\away3d\materials\passes\SkyBoxPass.as:110]
    at away3d.materials::MaterialBase/activatePass()[C:\workspace\flash\libs\lib_pano_away3d\src\away3d\materials\MaterialBase.as:408]
    at away3d.core.render::DefaultRenderer/drawSkyBox()[C:\workspace\flash\libs\lib_pano_away3d\src\away3d\core\render\DefaultRenderer.as:140]
    at away3d.core.render::DefaultRenderer/draw()[C:\workspace\flash\libs\lib_pano_away3d\src\away3d\core\render\DefaultRenderer.as:111]
    at away3d.core.render::RendererBase/executeRender()[C:\workspace\flash\libs\lib_pano_away3d\src\away3d\core\render\RendererBase.as:281]
    at away3d.core.render::DefaultRenderer/executeRender()[C:\workspace\flash\libs\lib_pano_away3d\src\away3d\core\render\DefaultRenderer.as:70]
    at away3d.core.render::RendererBase/render()[C:\workspace\flash\libs\lib_pano_away3d\src\away3d\core\render\RendererBase.as:245]
    at away3d.containers::View3D/render()[C:\workspace\flash\libs\lib_pano_away3d\src\away3d\containers\View3D.as:698]
    at co.beek.pano::Pano/onEnterFrame()[C:\workspace\flash\libs\lib_pano_away3d\src\co\beek\pano\Pano.as:1516]
```

Comment: It's not a question of clues, it's rather clear, you are overusing textures period and you are reaching the limit allowed for that type of resource for that graphic card. Overusing means you either try to work with too many textures OR you are working with texture with too high resolution OR you are not disposing correctly the previously used textures and they stay in memory OR a mix of all three.

Comment: ^ What he said. I would try away3d's forums as they might be able to help you better there.